# Unable to change 'Type' in security group rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to update security group inbound rules with desired IPs and select 'Type' as 'MSSQL', with my terraform, the rules are getting added with 'Custom TCP' type. below is my tf sec grp construct

```
resource "aws_security_group" "global_protect_db" {
  name        = "${local.service_name}-vpn_${var.traffic_port_db}"
  description = "HTTPS"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.systems-tools-vpc.id

  egress {
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    from_port   = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    to_port     = 0
  }

  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = concat(local.sg_split, formatlist(local.cidr))
    description = "SQL"
    from_port   = 1443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 1443
  }

  ingress {
    description     = "SQL from service"
    from_port   = 1443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 1443
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.service.id]
  }

}
```

Both these ingress rules should add IPs with type as 'MSSQL'. What change should be done?

Comment: Are there any errors? Are the connections not working?

Comment: No errors, but connections not working until I change type to mssql on console

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct MSSQL port?

Comment: that is port we have opened in dB to be able to connect. are the types auto selected based on port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port for MSSQL is **1433**, not `1443`. This will explain why you have issues with the SG and possibly connections.

Comment: In the question it's 1443 not 1143. :)

Comment: trying with 1433.